# Run application in apache localhost:8080

Tags: java, rest, restful-url

I have to run java URL="http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get" on Apache Tomcat but i am getting 404 Error. i want to get json response so what am i doing?

```
@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return track;

    }

public class NetClientGet {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");



            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Exception :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 404    at
>   com.mkyong.client.JerseyClientPost.main(JerseyClientPost.java:24)

Web.xml :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Have you registered JSONService as restful application ? which JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: yes, JSONService registered as restful application..I am using Jersey implementation.

Comment: post your web.xml servlets configuration.

Comment: `register(com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);`  register the JSON provider too.

Comment: still it`s not working....

Comment: still not working is not helping. unless you post all the related code like how and where you registered ?

Answer (score 0):

You're querying                     http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/product/get when the path should be                     http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/get;

Comment: Thnx :) can you give me an ans of this question?

Comment: What is going on here? Do you have a server running on your machine that outputs that data?

Comment: yup i have server running on my machine but i dont get this outputs data. its i want

Answer (score 0):

Your questions shows no indication of using `/RESTfulExample/rest` as base path.
So, assuming the name of the application is `RESTfulExample` it seems you're serving this path:
`/RESTfulExample/json/metallica/get`

Also, you should have a compilation error from the two ** in your code:
`**track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");`